# How regular expressions matching between the head tags content but does not contain itself

Tags: javascript, html, regex

```
<head>
    <title>hello world</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
</head>
```

I hope someone can help me, I was not familiar with the regular expression

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454

Comment: Could you explain the goal more clearly? As in what you are trying to find. The contents of the 'head' html itself can be obtained with: `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML;` if that is the goal?

Answer (score 1):

may be you can do like this;

```
var htmlText = "<head><title>hello world</title><meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport"></head>";
       inner = htmlText.replace(/<head>(.+)<\/head>/,"$1");

<head>(.+)<\/head>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/M_9HatCmJL3dqLSo)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand the question but if it's the innerHTML you're after and you insist on using REGEX than this might help:

```
\>(.*?)\<
```

See here: https://regex101.com/r/aE0aV0/1